# Access and File Picker

Tags: ms-access, filepicker

I want to fill a textbox with a file path so that I can then add the filepath as a hyperlink in a record.

I created a button and wrote this subroutine:

```
Private Sub Browsebutt_Click()
Dim fd As Object
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(3) 'msoFileDialogFilePicker
With fd
    .Filters.Clear
    .InitialFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
    .Title = "Select File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .Filters.Add "All Files (*.*)", "*.*"
    '.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList'
    If .Show Then
        Me.Offlink = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End With
```

Everything looks fine but the issue is when I browse to something stored in my company NAS. The path looks like this:

Z:\Folder1\File

It doesn't work on click, if instead of this I use the drag and drop function directly into the access table (not in the form) I obtain something like this:

\192.168.0.155\archive\Folder1\File

and it actually works, when I click on the link it opens my file.

So I was wondering if there is a way to have the file picker to provide the path with full ip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word VBA to retrieve IP address "silently"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972532/word-vba-to-retrieve-ip-address-silently)

Comment: @June7 kinda different from that, since it this involves a drive letter from a network share, and he hasn't isolated the network address yet. You still need to do network drive letter to network address before you can do network address to IP.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this will require some steps, and might depend slightly on your setup:

You can't change the file picker behaviour a lot, so I'm going to change out the drive letter for the UNC path. Depending on how your drive is mapped, it will either return a server name (such as `\\MyServer` or `\\www.AnUrl.tld`), or an IP address

First, I'm going to use a couple of helper functions I found [here](http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/mvba/mvba-mapped-drives-unc.htm) and adapted to use late bindings and increase usability.

**Helper 1: Input: a full path. Output: the drive letter from that path**

```
Public Function ParseDriveLetter(ByVal path As String) As String
    'Get drive letter from path
    ParseDriveLetter = vbNullString
    On Error GoTo err_ParseDriveLetter
    Dim oFileSystem As Object ' Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFolder As Object 'Scripting.Folder
    '    Next line throws error if mapping not available
    Set oFolder = oFileSystem.GetFolder(path)
    If (oFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print "ParseDriveLetter: Folder '" & path & "' is invalid"
    Else
        ParseDriveLetter = oFileSystem.GetDriveName(oFolder.path)
    End If
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFileSystem = Nothing
    Exit Function

err_ParseDriveLetter:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 76:
        '    Path not found -- invalid drive letter or letter not mapped
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error no. " & CStr(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
            "Was caused by " & Err.Source, vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "Error in function ParseDriveLetter"
    End Select
End Function
```

**Helper 2: Input: a drive letter from a mapped network drive. Output: the location the drive is mapped to**

```
Public Function GetMappedPathFromDrive(ByVal drive As String) As String
    Dim oWshNetwork As Object 'New WshNetwork
    Dim oDrives As Object 'New WshCollection
    Set oWshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    '   The EnumNetworkDrives method returns a collection.
    '   This collection is an array that associates pairs of items ? network drive local names and their associated UNC names.
    '   Even-numbered items in the collection represent local names of logical drives.
    '   Odd-numbered items represent the associated UNC share names.
    '   The first item in the collection is at index zero (0)
    Set oDrives = oWshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
    Dim i                                   As Integer
    For i = 0 To oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
        '   Drive is oDrives.Item(i), UNC is oDrives.Item(i + 1)
        If (0 = StrComp(drive, oDrives.Item(i), vbTextCompare)) Then
            '   We have matched the drive letter.  Copy the UNC path and finish
            GetMappedPathFromDrive = oDrives.Item(i + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set oDrives = Nothing
    Set oWshNetwork = Nothing
End Function
```

**And now, the implementation in your code:**

```
Me.Offlink = Replace(.SelectedItems(1), ParseDriveLetter(.SelectedItems(1)), GetMappedPathFromDrive(ParseDriveLetter(.SelectedItems(1))))
```

Note that if this returns the server name instead of the IP address, you can use the post @June7 referred to to get the IP address.

Comment: If I understood well how it works I think you missed some brackets at the end of the Replace function. Anyway it doesn't work but I didn't debug it yet, maybe I missed something.

Comment: I think I have  a problem with those functions. Is there some place in with I need to put them or it's just enough to paste them in the form code?

Comment: Made some fixes. You can test the separate functions by using the immediate window. `?ParseDriveLetter("Z:\Folder1")` should return `Z:`, and `GetMappedPathFromDrive("Z:")` should return `\\192.168.0.155\archive`